# How do I mimic floats with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float

I am trying to use flexbox like floats. I would like 1 child to form a column on the right and the remaining children to form another column on the left. I can't add in additional HTML -- I can only work with CSS.

I've figured out how to do this, but **I just need both columns to align at the top**. My current code has the left column slightly below the right column.

https://jsfiddle.net/o2fbtuLc/

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  max-width: 48%;
}

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child right">Right</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need grid, not flexbox, for this.

Comment: `display:table/table-cell`mixed with `block/flex ` works too where your browser and grid do not go along ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items). Also I removed `flex-direction: column` and added `max-width: 100%` for elements after second element.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 48%;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}

.child:nth-child(3) {
  order: 3;
}

.child:nth-child(4) {
  order: 4;
}

.right {
  order: 2;
}

.child:nth-child(n + 3) {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child right">Right</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
</div>
```

If `.right` is taller, we can consider using `grid-area`.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:  "left1 right" 
                        "left2 right" 
                        "left3 right";
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  height: 30px;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: left1;
}

.child:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: left2;
}

.child:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: left3;
}

.right {
  background: red;
  height: 80px;
  grid-area: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child right">Right</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but what happens when <div class="child right">Right</div> is not the same height as the children in the left column? If it's taller?

Comment: @Weebs I added grid solution also.

Answer (score 1):

just use flexbox as it was intended!

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div></div>
  <div class="child right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Grid can do that:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.child {
  max-width: 48%;
  grid-column: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child right">Right</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `grid` *(IE 11 involved maybe ?)* , the old way via the table-display, can do too :

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  direction: rtl;/* alike a flow column reverse here */
  text-align: left;
  border: solid;
}

.child {
  direction: ltr;/* ! reset flow direction  ;)*/
  border: solid;
}

.right {/* i will also expand if first col is longer than myself  */
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;/* set column width here ! left over will be for the other one(s). */
}

/* margins ? */
.bis {border-spacing:2px;}
.bis .child {margin-right:2px;}
.bis .right + .child ~ .child {margin-top:2px;}
.bis .right{text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child right">Right</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="parent bis">
  <div class="child right">possible gaps /  VH-align</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
  <div class="child">two<br>lines</div>
  <div class="child">Left</div>
</div>
```